# Toprope webbing anchor with figure 8 knots

Tags: rock-climbing, knots

I recently made a toprope anchor extending from a tree about 15' over the edge of the cliff using 1" webbing. The webbing was looped around the tree using a figure 8 follow-through, with sufficient tail and a simple stopper knot as well. A figure-8 on a bight was tied at the master point (opp opposed lockers), where the anchor joined a sling from the single good bolt (the other was loose), the rest of the webbing simply coiled up at the top of the cliff. See the fantastic attached image.[image: Sketch of anchor]

My question is: People seem to think poorly of figure-eights with flat webbing, but in this setup they seemed perfectly fine and I don't see why one wouldn't use them (other than, perhaps, simplicity in using other knots). Is this anchor safe with the figure-8s? Should they be tied differently?

Comment: Just to clarify-- it was anchored to a tree and a bolt? And it had a single figure 8 at the master point? And two lockers off the master point? And your question is about the figure 8 in the webbing, the overall setup, or both?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion -- yes it was anchored to the tree and bolt, so the whole anchor system was definitely redundant. 

Actually, I only later realized I should have tied both the webbing and sling from the bolt into a single master point fig8 for better equalization, as the anchor was setup there was a fig8 on the webbing and just a sling from the bolt, with the lockers running through both loops. 

Mainly though I was concerned with the knots I had tied in the webbing part.

Comment: You had a caribiner on the end of the Bight right? Please say you didn't have the rope running though the webbing?

Comment: PS, I love your drawing

Comment: Yes! There were two locking opposite opposed biners through the webbing/sling, the rope then running through the biners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Knot is a knot and its usually not something to get tied up in knots about.

An simple overhand is a better knot in tape, purely because a Fig8 is impossible to lie neatly. As far as the question goes, Fig 8 is good. With any knot if its the only one you know, its far safer than any other knot you could use. Fig 8 might be a bit hard to undo at the end of the climb, especially if you loaded it, but the overhand can be a b!tch anyway.

Often others are are showing you other knots, or telling you you are using the wrong one, to prove how smarty-pants they are, not because they care for your safety.

The one piece of webbing giving single point failure - that is a far more serious concern.

Comment: The webbing was backed up by a bolt with a sling